# Python remove ( after fetching data from SQL table

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm fetching data from a SQL table and my results look like this: [(242,43,345,345,23),(2,34,344,243,34)] but I need my data in this format: [[242,43,345,345,23],[2,34,344,243,34]]

Whats the most efficient way to transform the data?

Comment: @abiessu Thats not working, because my result isn't a string  Its a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial value is a list of tuples. You're seemingly asking to convert it instead to a list of lists. One option is to use a list comprehension to iterate over the tuples, and convert each to a list:

```
>>> val =  [(242,43,345,345,23),(2,34,344,243,34)]
>>> [list(x) for x in val]
[[242, 43, 345, 345, 23], [2, 34, 344, 243, 34]]
```

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot for the fast answer!